# is there a throttle or firewall limitation using the consumption API of the Azure EA

Tags: azure, api, consumption

The API calls for EA consumption API from a pwsh script on a Azure VM are stuck 99% of the time.
There is no timeout but no response after 2 hours of execution...

The same script on a stand alone PC runs in less than 1 minute with the same code, same pwsh version.

Is there a throttle or other limit when calling this API from an Azure VM / service ?

example :

```
$myUri = "https://consumption.azure.com/v3/enrollments/$enrollmentNumber/usagedetailsbycustomdate?startTime=$DateStart&endTime=$DateEnd"
$AccessToken = "Bearer $ApiKey"
$myHeaders = @{ 'Authorization' = $AccessToken}
$response=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $myUri -Headers $myHeaders -Method GET
```

the variables ($ApiKey, $DateStart, $DateEnd, ... , ...) are correctly set, if there is an issue, i ve got a http error code so the endpoint is there and process the request... but no return...no timeout...

i try with a one day diff between datestart and dateend.

Comment: Could you post the script or at least a [mcve] that is blocked as well ?

Comment: done, i've edited the post

Comment: The Power BI Connector "Microsoft Consumption Insight" has also an issue : Data source error: The 'Consumed Quantity' column does not exist in the rowset. Table: Usage Details.
Cluster URI: WABI-US-NORTH-CENTRAL-redirect.analysis.windows.net

Comment: Did you find any answer to this? Running into the same problem at the moment...